# Load Heavy Object from IoC Container blocks the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, async-await, castle-windsor

We have a WPF application (.NET 4.0, can't change due to Windows Server 2003 and XP compatibility) using BCL to support async/await.
For DI and aspects we use Castle IoC and, to access the Oracle databases, we use NHibernate. Our problem is the following:

I have implemented a UoW pattern that, at some point, has to receive an ISessionFactory. Since we use `async`/`await`, the first business action the user invokes will load the ISessionFactory singleton for the first time, which may take some seconds due to mapping (even if I store that information in a file) and, because the async/await it will execute on the UI, blocking the application. What I'm trying to achieve is to load the ISessionFactory on a separate thread, trying to prevent the UI from blocking. Because this first load may occur at any screen, at any given time, I believe the IoC container should be the perfect place to put this logic, but I'm failing to prevent the UI from blocking.

Here is the normal registration:

```
    Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(
        k =>
            Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    () => OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(
                        c => c.Is(k.Resolve<ISifarmaConnectionString>().Value))
#if DEBUG
                    .ShowSql().FormatSql()
#endif
                )
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ISifarmaUnitOfWork>())
#if DEBUG
                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor()))
#endif
                .BuildSessionFactory()).LifestyleSingleton(),
```

Here is what tried (because I return the concrete type and not a `Task<ISessionFactory>` I can't await here which is obviously blocking the UI with the `Task.WaitAll(task)`):

```
    Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(
        k =>
        {
            var task =
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () =>
                        Fluently.Configure()
                            .Database(
                                () => OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(
                                    c => c.Is(k.Resolve<ISifarmaConnectionString>().Value))
#if DEBUG
                                .ShowSql().FormatSql()
#endif
                            )
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ISifarmaUnitOfWork>())
#if DEBUG
                            .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor()))
#endif
                            .BuildSessionFactory());
            Task.WaitAll(task);
            return task.Result;
        }).LifestyleSingleton(),
```

Is there any way to do this without blocking the UI?
I also tried, when the application starts, to create a task that makes `container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>()` but if a user is fast enough at the login screen, the object haven't loaded yet.

Comment: You are still waiting for the task to finish inside the registration method, so you don't gain anything. The code is still synchronous

Comment: Yes, I know that. Thats what I meant by "which is obviously blocking the UI with the Task.WaitAll(task)".

Comment: Why must you return `ISessionFactory` and not a task of it?

Comment: What you need is asynchronous resolution which isn't supported by IoCs at the moment (I think). A workaround would be to register a Lazy<ISessionFactory> and force it to initialize eg in a throwaway task. This way, you'd only block if the factory wan't already initialized by the time the first form asked for it.

Comment: Why not move the entire `Component.For` to a new thread?

Comment: @i3arnon having a public SifarmaUnitOfWork(Task<ISessionFactory> sessionFactoryTask) doesn't seems correct to me. Also, it is a singleton object and 'N' UoW will use it, unless I made sessionFactoryTask.Result (which would block the UI), it would be impossible to await multiple times in the same object.

Comment: @JoãoSimões I suggest you choose a path. Either do it completely `async` or just let it go and do it synchronously. Don't try to mix those.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Caslte IoC already guarantees that, from my testings because it prevents concurrency issues (my task is already loading the object, and when it tries to resolve the ISessionFactory to the 'LoginBC' it blocks. Normally this saves 1-2 seconds, depends how fast the user writes its credentials.

Comment: Then@i3arnon 's idea is better. although it means you'd have to rewrite your methods to expect a `Task<ISessionFactory>` instead of `ISessionFactory`.

Comment: @i3arnon is it possible to 'await' multiple times in the same object?

Comment: `await` just waits, it doesn't affect the object it targets. BTW why don't you create the factory behind a splash screen? Can the user do anything if you don't have a SessionFactory?

Comment: @JoãoSimões I don't know what that means. You can use `await` multiple times in the same method if that's what you mean...

Comment: @i3arnon the 'Task<ISessionFactory>' is a singleton so, all my methods would receive the same object. If all made, lets assume, 'using(var session = (await sessionTaskFactory).OpenSession())' I believe I would receive an exception (can't recall now exactly)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct, that's something we need to implement, we just had enough time to focus on it, but it certainly is the most "clean" solution.

Comment: @JoãoSimões got it. You ask whether it's okay to `await` the same completed task multiple times? If so, that's **perfectly fine**. The only way you would get an exception is if the task was faulted to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is create a proxy class for `ISessionFactory` that depends upon a `Lazy<ISessionFactory>`. This proxy can be injected into anyone who needs an `ISessionFactory`, and you can trigger the creation of the `ISessionFactory` yourself in a background thread during initialization:

```
public class LazySessionFactoryProxy : ISessionFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<ISessionFactory> factory;

    public LazySessionFactoryProxy(Lazy<ISessionFactory> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public ISession OpenSession() {
        return this.factory.Value.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

This can be registered as follows:

```
var lazy = new Lazy<ISessionFactory>(() => ...);

container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactory>() 
    .Instance(new LazySessionFactoryProxy(lazy)));

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => lazy.Value);
```

By creating a proxy class inside your composition root, you allow the rest of the application to stay oblivious about the performance bottleneck in the session factory. Injecting a `Lazy<ISessionFactory>` or `Task<ISessionFactory>` into every consumer means that you need to make sweeping changes throughout your application (violation of [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)) and means you are leaking implementation details (the fact that your specific session factory is costly to create) out of the abstraction (violation of [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)).

You can even create a `LazySessionFactoryProxy` that will show a wait screen when some code calls the `OpenSession` and will automatically close it when the factory is initialized. Fun part is that this is all possible without having to change one single line of code in your application; just by changing the wiring of your composition root.

Do note that a problem that 'asynchronous resolves' are not supported by DI containers, but having a asynchronous resolve is simply not useful. Building your [object graphs should be really fast](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/) because [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), and slow parts should be isolated in the way I showed, instead of polluting the application with it.

Comment: Castle IoC already lazy-loads the object. This solution, which is a good one, doesn't solve the problem where the initial 'Task.Factory.StartNew(() => lazy.Value);' haven't finished before I need the 'ISessionFactory'. This is something I already made (as stated in the question) where, right after registering everything in the container, I created a task to trigger the lazy load. The problem is, if the user is really fast to type its credentials, the business logic would require the object before the task terminated. None the less, this still saves about 3-4 seconds of UI locking.

Comment: @JoãoSimões: In the case with the supplied `LazySessionFactoryProxy`, the UI would block until the factory is created, but blocking will be less, since it is kicked off directly on startup. But since it's unlikely that the user can do anything useful with the application without the database, I would say that blocking is not an issue, and if it is, present him with a wait screen triggered by the proxy, as I described in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I can see this happening. I was already thinking, for some time, to have a business object to get persistence state (is DB alive, etc) and I don't mind to remove the login logic from the UoW (we have a procedure that uses Oracle password) and resolve this object (I don't want the presentation project to know what a ISessionFactory is) in a separate task right after container registration and after successful login, the latest triggering our loading screen until completed. Because after login the user goes to a Metro menu, this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the task instead of the result of that task (i.e. `Task<ISessionFactory>` instead of `ISessionFactory`) and `await` that task whenever you need the result:

```
Component.For<Task<ISessionFactory>>().UsingFactoryMethod(
    k => Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
            Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    () => OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(
                        c => c.Is(k.Resolve<ISifarmaConnectionString>().Value))
#if DEBUG
                    .ShowSql().FormatSql()
#endif
                )
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ISifarmaUnitOfWork>())
#if DEBUG
                .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetInterceptor(new SqlStatementInterceptor()))
#endif
                .BuildSessionFactory());
    }).LifestyleSingleton(),
```

There's nothing wrong with awaiting a task more than once. It would only throw an exception if the task is faulted (and then it would always throw).

Since in most cases, the task would already be completed, `await` would continue on synchronously and extract the result. For example:

```
using(var session = (await sessionTaskFactory).OpenSession())
```

Comment: Ok, I made some tests and it is true that I can await multiple times the same task. I'll just adapt the code, but this certainly is the solution. I had the impression that awaiting multiple times would throw an exception even if successful (I believe it was a null reference exception when the code behind was trying to get the awaiter) but that time I was intercepting the method invocations and changing the Task<TResult> so it probably was related to my code. Let me just make some tests but I'm sure this solves my problem and will mark this as the solution.

Comment: @JoãoSimões sure.. let me know if you have issues.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it would require the session to be obtained async. My UoW has a single associated Session (or if EF, a context), I seriously wouldn't like my repositories to have to make 'return (await GetSession()).Where(p => p.Name.Contains(nameFilter))'

Comment: @JoãoSimões You can use `GetSession().Result` when you know that task already completed

Comment: That would be the equivalent to use the await, but requiring logic to know if the object was already loaded or not. I don't mind our code to know that a session is an heavy object and should be loaded async, but requiring to use async every time I needed it would bother me to the end of times. I'll use @Steve suggestion, specially because it has the minimum impact in our code, but this still is a very valid solution, thanks!